# awk: preserve row order and remove duplicate strings (mirrors) when generating data

Tags: awk, comparison, batch-processing

I have two text files

g1.txt

```
 alfa beta;www.google.com
 Light Dweller - CR, Technical Metal;http://alfa.org;http://beta.org;http://gamma.org;
```

g2.txt

```
Jack to ride.zip;http://alfa.org;
JKr.rui.rar;http://gamma.org;
Nofj ogk.png;http://gamma.org;
```

I use this command to run my awk script

```
awk -f ./join2.sh g1.txt g2.txt > "g3.txt"
```

and I obtain this output

```
Light Dweller - CR, Technical Metal;http://alfa.org;http://beta.org;http://gamma.org;;Jack to ride.zip;http://alfa.org;JKr.rui.rar;http://gamma.org;Nofj ogk.png;http://gamma.org;
alfa beta;www.google.com;
```

What are the problems?
**1.** row order is not conservated, for example in the output file g3.txt, the line `alfa beta;www.google.com;` is after the line `Light...`. when it should be first, as you can see in g1.txt
**2.** I have many mirror strings in `Light..` line, you can see that in g3.txt

```
http://alfa.org
http://gamma.org
http://gamma.org
```

are repeated in same row.

**What kind of output for rows, instead, do I want?** *Like this:*

```
alfa beta;www.google.com
Light Dweller - CR, Technical Metal;http://alfa.org;http://beta.org;http://gamma.org;Jack to ride.zip;JKr.rui.rar;Nofj ogk.png;
```

**First:** I try to implement a function that check if there are ugual strings inside a row, for example do you see in my row output `Light Dweller - CR, Technical Metal...` that there are identical string inside that row? For example `http://alfa.org` and `http://gamma.org` ? Ok, I don't want this. **I want each string, enclosed within delimiters; is present only once and only once for each row.**
 This rule should only apply to the output file, g3.txt

**Second:** I want that original order of rows in g1.txt must be maintained in the g3.txt output file. For example, in g1.txt I have

```
alfa beta ... 
Light Dweller ...
```

but my script returns to me a different ordering

```
Light Dweller ...
alfa beta ...
```

I want to prevent reordering of rows

My **join2.sh** script is this

```
#! /usr/bin/awk  -f

BEGIN {
  OFS=FS=";"
  C=0;
}
{
  if (ARGIND == 1) {
     X = $NF
     T0[$NF] = C++
     $NF = ""
     if (T1[X]) {
        T1[X] = T1[X] $0
     } else {
        T1[X] = $0
     }
  } else {
     X = $NF
     T0[$NF] = C++
     $NF = ""
     if (T2[X]) {
        T2[X] = T2[X] $0
     } else {
        T2[X] = $0
     }
  }
}

END {
  for (X in T0) {
    # concatenate T1[X] and X, since T1[X] ends with ";"
    print T1[X]  X, T2[X]
  }
}
```

SOLUTION:
[image]

Comment: Why is this labeled Powershell?

Comment: sorry, i mistake, now I remove

Comment: I try to do 2 things: implement a function that check if there are ugual strings inside a row, for example do you see in my row output `Light Dweller - CR, Technical Metal...` that there are identical string inside that row? For example `http://alfa.org` and `http://gamma.org` ? Ok, I don't want this. I want the string, delimited by separator `;`must be present within the line only once

Comment: second: I want to prevent reordering of rows.I want that original order of rows in g1.txt must be maintained in the g3.txt output file. For example, in g1.txt I have

`alfa beta ... 
Light Dweller ...` 

but my script returns to me a different ordering

`Light Dweller ...
alfa beta ...` I want to prevent reordering of rows

Comment: can you have duplicate URLs in `g1.txt` originally also?

Comment: @anubhava you can't change `g1.txt` and `g2.txt` content (hence if there are duplicates URLs or other duplicate strings into `g1-g2.txt` you can't touch them) but you can read them only because I need to write the new content into `g3.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should process `g2.txt` first like this:

```sh
cat join2.awk

BEGIN {
  OFS=FS=";"
}
ARGIND == 1 {
   map[$2] = ($2 in map ? map[$2] OFS : "") $1
   next
}
{
   r = $0;
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      if ($i in map)
         r = r OFS map[$i]
   $0 = r
}
1
```

Then use it as:

```sh
awk -f join2.awk g2.txt g1.txt
```

```
alfa beta;www.google.com
Light Dweller - CR, Technical Metal;http://alfa.org;http://beta.org;http://gamma.org;;Jack to ride.zip;JKr.rui.rar;Nofj ogk.png
```

Comment: great! Really thanks! Now I understand :) https://imgur.com/gWXprrw.png

Comment: Sorry if I'm bothering you, but I noticed that your script doesn't work if I have this text, yet, it seemed to me that it has the same formatting. Can you help me understand why? Text is this https://pastebin.com/Fur0XfkP

Comment: ok, maybe is due that I need to jump on the same row also text with suffix `&st=30;` or `&st=60;` or `&st=90;` and so on .. see you later

Comment: I posted question here, if want take a look. https://superuser.com/questions/1601402/when-script-carries-common-strings-from-rows-lines-are-truncated