# extend awk script for multiple lines in both text files and not if both files have just a single record

Tags: awk

I CAN generate this **3**.txt output

```
AA;BB;CC;DD;
```

from 2 text files. Both files only have a single record

**1**.txt

```
AA;BB;
```

**2**.txt

```
CC;DD;BB;AA;
```

I use this awk script.

```
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=";"
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(!seen[$i]++){ val=(val?val OFS:"")$i }
  }
  print val
  delete seen
  val=""
}
```

I use in this way, I use `paste` command to combine both the files and then processing its output by `awk` command.

```
paste 1st.txt 2nd.txt | awk -f tst.awk > "3.txt"
```

But what I want? 
I need to consider more of one single record. I try to adapt this script for this situation. You can see that now both files have not only a single records.

**1**.txt

```
UU;    
AA;BB;
ZZ;KK;
```

**2**.txt

```
CC;DD;BB;AA;
LL;KK;
GH;ZZ;SS;
```

output **3**.txt that I try to generate is this

```
UU;
AA;BB;CC;DD;
ZZ;KK;LL;GH;SS;
```

**processing logic:**

Code above just uses literal strings in a hash lookup of array indices so it doesn't care what characters you have in your input. 
However about sample output: if in **2**.txt there are common fields also in **1**.txt.for example `BB;AA;` then you need concatenate them in a single row, i.e `AA;BB;CC;DD`; Ordering is not required, for example is not relevant if output is `BB;AA;DD;CC;` Only condition that is required is avoid duplicates fields in the same row

When I say 'avoid duplicates' I mean avoid this output

```
AA;BB;CC;DD;BB;AA;
```

because output should be

```
AA;BB;CC;DD;
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts. Sorry but your Logic of getting output is not clear, could you please explain more clearly in this question.

Comment: Looks like the same homework as https://stackoverflow.com/q/64952864/7552

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/q/64963735/1745001

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic regular expressions in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64952864/dynamic-regular-expressions-in-awk)

Comment: I;m confused, if you have `UU; ` and `CC;DD;BB;AA;` why wouldn't be `UU;CC;DD;BB;AA;` ?? There are no duplicate fields between `1.txt` and `2.txt` on the first line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}
{sub(/;$/,"")}
NR==FNR{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;++i)
        for (j=1;j<=NF;++j)
            if (j!=i&&!b[$i,$j]++)
                a[$i,++c[$i]]=$j
    next
}
{
    delete b
    for (i=1;i<=NF;++i)
        ++b[$i]
    for (i=1;i<=NF;++i)
        for (j=1;j<=c[$i];++j)
            if (!b[a[$i,j]]++)
                $(NF+1)=a[$i,j]
    print
}
```

Use it like this:

```
awk -f script.awk 2.txt 1.txt
```

Here are some previous questions:

- https://superuser.com/q/1600078
- [awk: preserve row order and remove duplicate strings (mirrors) when generating data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64733653)
- https://superuser.com/q/1600557
- https://superuser.com/q/1601402
- https://superuser.com/q/1602713
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/64929865
- https://superuser.com/q/1604046
- [Dynamic regular expressions in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64952864)
- [Truncation of strings after running awk script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64963735)